# Flutter FirebaseFirestore [cloud_firestore/failed-precondition] Issue

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to execute a query that has `where` and `orderBy` in a `FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('collectionName').where('fieldName1', isEqualTo: 'value1').orderBy('fieldName1', descending:true).snapshots()` statement. I've also created a composite index for both fields defined in the above statement.

Though, I'm getting this error:

```
[log] [cloud_firestore/failed-precondition] Operation was rejected because the system is not in a state required for the operation's execution. If performing a query, ensure it has been indexed via the Firebase console.
```

I'm using

```
firebase_core: ^1.3.0
cloud_firestore: ^2.3.0
```

Comment: Can you share the index created? Also are you using where method along with orderBy on same field?

Answer (score 0):

I guess something might be wrong with the index. I recommend you to follow these steps:

1. Delete the index.
2. Run the function again. An error will be thrown.
3. Check the logs with `adb logcat`.
4. Some information will appear to create the appropriate index.

Comment: Checked it. Though there's no link or associated link to create the index.